# Testing Backbone View with Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, testing, backbone.js, mocha.js

I have a simple Backbone View and a simple unit test written in Mocha.

View code:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#myDiv',
initialize: function(options) {
  if(options.model)
    this.model = options.model;
  }
});
```

My test code:

```
var view;
describe('myView Test', function(){
  before(function(done){
    view = new MyView();
  });
});
```

When I try to create a new View, I receive;

```
Application View "before all" hook:
TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #myDiv
at backbone.js line 1203
```

I am not so sure what is missing here, any insights?

Thank you,
sakal

Comment: Not sure, but try to call done() or remove the done argument.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things wrong here.

First, as @Aron-Woost mentioned, you are having the before hook run asynchronously.  If this is what you want to do, you need to call `done();` at the end of hook or you will get a timeout error.  If you want to run the hook synchronously, don't pass the `done` argument into the function.

Next,  when you are initializing your view in the `before all` hook you are not passing an options object argument.  Not having this should cause an error in your backbone view.  Since `options` is not being passed in, you should be getting an error on the `if` statement along the lines of `Cannot read property 'model' of undefined`.  Easy fix for this, pass as empty object`{}` so you have something like this: `view = new MyView({});`.

Not sure how you are producing the exact error you have listed above.  Have you provided all of your code for this problem?